# Compiled Application with Ruby config files (yml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I compiled a program from source on mac os x which tells me to use the supplied example config files, but how can I run a specific config file?

Readme shows what to edit in the config but not how to load it.
More specifically this program (http://github.com/carsonmcdonald/HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following should work:

```
./http_streamer.rb example-configs/config-simple.yml
```

basically the name of the config file goes as the first argument to the script.